# Where to ask a question about the best "zsh + iTerm2" for Windows alternative

Tags: discussion, on-topic, site-rec

I would like to ask this question (just a draft for now)

> I recently moved from MacOS to Windows 10, and I need to find a good terminal + bash substitute for what I had on the Mac (iTerm2 + zsh + Oh my zsh!). I do most of my work on a remote Linux server, to which I connect by SSH. Thus I need:
>
> - tab support,
> - SSH/SCP support, with key agent support (to avoid entering my password every time I connect to the remote server)
> - ...

Is it appropriate for the SE hierarchy? If so, do I ask here or on Software Recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any questions asking for "best" software with a particular set of features is off topic on Super User and should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

You would need to clearly define your requirements and read their [question quality guidelines](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).